# How to show a page content only in AMP version and hide it in non-AMP version

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I am using AMP for WP plugin in my Wordpress site. Actually, I need to show a particular page content only in the AMP version of the web page by hiding the same in the Non-AMP version.
I need the HTML/CSS code to achieve the above results. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You want to display the AMP version on all devices, So you can convert your Wordpress theme into an AMP theme, without plugins.